# How to save stream in mp4 format?

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, ffmpeg, rtmp

By default nginx rtmp module records video stream in `.flv` format if `record` option is enabled, but I need `.mp4`

I found that video can be converted to `.mp4` when record has finished with `exec_record_done` callback and `ffmpeg`

Is there any way to record video in `.mp4` format or at least convert it to this format on the fly?

Comment: Have you talked to the developer?

Comment: Something tells me, this is not supported: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518366/setup-a-vod-for-mp4-video-files-using-nginx-and-rtmp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can't do it on fly.
On the other hand, you can just resave it in mp4.
You can try to use directly ffmpeg as it supports output https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment 
Some sort of this, might go:
**`ffmpeg -i rtsp://admin:admin@10.1.1.1:554/ch1-s1 -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 600 -segment_format mp4 "out%03d.mp4"`**